# How to avoid to mark as unchanged and later to modified because of a unique constrain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table that has a unique constraint for two fields, (IDParent, positionInParent).

```
Parent
{
    IDParent;
}

Child
{
    IDChild;
    IDParent;
    PositionInParent;
}
```

I can only have a child in a position, and I want that when I delete a child, the child with position +1 is changed to position -1, to don't have gaps.

The problem is that when I save the changes in the dataContext, because EF does not ensure the order of the operations, so I get an exception because of the unique constraint, it seems that the update of the affected children is done before updating the deleted child.

So I am doing this, that it works, but I wonder if there is a better way to solve this problem:

- Change the state of affected children to unchanged.
- Save changes, so the deleted child is marked as deleted.
- Change the state to affected children to modified.
- Save changes again.

But this makes me an extra save changes and also to use two loops to change the state of the affected children.

Is this a unique way or there is a better way to do that?

I am using EF Core 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved on a DB level by using AFTER DELETE trigger.

From the code perspective - you can probably delete and save, and then update and save.
To prevent side effects do all this inside a transaction